# Gutenberg TextareaControl escapes html

Tags: block-editor

I built a block which has 3 TextareaControl. HTML, SCRIPT, STYLE. SCRIPT and STYLE are fine but TextareaControl escapes html.

```
<p>test</p>
```

becomes

```
&lt;p>test&lt;/p>
```

I searched Google and some people adviced RawHTML but it is deprecated.

What should I do?